# Split arbitratry string into lines

Tags: latex

I have an arbitratry string, something like QKOTRFLARGEBRAAFFALGORITHMMIMISSSTUPIDCROCODOLCONCEALEDKSBABA...
and I need to tell LaTeX to split this string neatly into lines. It is not a word, there should be no '-' when splitting line. Just fit these data into lines, break wherever it suits.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26174/allow-line-break-but-without-inserting-a-dash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully used the [seqsplit](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit) package for that.